# "Account unlock" when not connected to internet?

Tags: security, lock-screens, password

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone. I see this screen when I press "Forgot Password" in the pattern lock screen that comes by default with the phone:

[image]

My Question is: How would my account be unlocked when 
(i) "Wifi" is turned off and
(ii) "Packet Data" is disabled?

Comment: Just as a guess I'd imagine the details could be stored in the phone's memory (presumably as hashed values, storing a plain text password would be a big no no). The entered values are then checked against the locally stored hashed ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes.

Comment: Ah, it's not a big deal then.. Just create a Nandroid backup. Do factory reset. And, restore everything from Nandroid backup using Titanium backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Search and download Unlocker or Screen Lock Bypass app from internet (which are no longer available in Play Store).
2. Push it to the system from recovery ([with update.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1610121)).
3. Start the system.

Comment: You should be very cautious about installing random apps from discussion forums...

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to internet by pressing the on/off key and selecting enable data connection mode ...

Answer (score 0):

turn off mobile phone and press volum up + home butten + power button press come out samsung logo and realse the samsung logo to boot in to recovery select the swipe default factory reset

Comment: You should also mention that this deletes all data in the internal storage of the phone.